# how to update a table with a random record from another table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve a random record from a Query(trackList) and update a table (setList) with that record using VBA in MS Access. I've assigned integer values from my recordset and when I run the debug everything runs correctly. when I call this up from a batch file it continues to retrieve the records in alphanumeric order. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("_Sun00Q")

strName = rst.Fields("PLNames")
strSetName = rst.Fields("SetName")

Set rst2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strName & "_trackList_RndOrd")
intPLNid = rst2.Fields("PLNid")
intId = rst2.Fields("id")

SQL = "UPDATE " & strSetName & " SET id=" & intId & " WHERE PLNid=" & intPLNid

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open your first table as a recordset, generate a [random integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function), then move the AbsolutePosition of the recordset to that random integer. That should get you to a random spot in the recordset. Then add that record to your second table.